# Sending location of passive RFID chip from RFID to Android App

Tags: java, android, tracking, rfid

I am creating an Android app that allows me to track missing items. I will be using a passive RFID chip that will be attached to items I want to be able to track. When the Android app is launched, it will retrieve the location info (specifically longitude and latitude) from the passive RFID chip and display it for the user.

I have extremely minimum coding experience and was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction of where/how I can add this tracking capability to my app?

Thanks

Comment: dude did u get a solution ? i am also looking for an answer.